# What's the quickest way to navigate to the top of a class in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, class, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

If I'm editing deep within the body of a class, what would be the quickest (ie. fewest keyboard shortcuts) way to navigate to the top of the class declaration (the line that contains "class ClassName"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, to get to the navigation bar, then hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to select the currently focused class.

Comment: when peer programming, simply ask your peer to do it!

Comment: I guess you could use the Speech Recognition API :-)

Answer (score 0):

If for some perverted reason you'd rather use the mouse, you can select the list of functions at the top right and then just select "Declarations"; that should take you to the top of the class definition. At least that works for me in VS2005...

Answer (score 0):

Create bookmarks on all your methods / class declarations. Then use (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) for the next bookmark, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) for the previous bookmark. Then you can just "thumb" through them somewhat. Works great for me. Or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> to take you to the very top of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Control + G which is goto line number, and then type 1

Comment: Do you think it is possible that the top of a class is not found at line 1?